# Creating filter which sends error mails back

Tags: email, webserver, spam-prevention

In the next year I want to set up a personal email server with custom domain etc.

For spam issues, I want to create an email filter which sends in case of spam the exact same message back, like it would be, if the address wouldn't exist. This way, the spammers can not tell if it is a filter or the address doesn't exist.

Is there an existing solution, which supports this or supports tools to create this?

I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Please keep in mind that spammers often use fake sender addresses. So your replies might end up spamming innocent people (and you could be blocked or added to some blacklist by some ISP, just because you're sending a lot of non-deliverables).

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/146855/how-to-make-spamassasin-reject-mail-based-on-score#569372

Comment: @mtak Right. Haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have many solution for this, if you use postfix you could use:

- [Postgrey](https://postgrey.schweikert.ch/)
- [Spamassassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/)

and you could also enable smtpd_client_restrictions in posfix by adding a rule to reject_rbl_client.
For example in your `master.cf` file:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        permit
```

Comment: while your post has good content in it with respect of blocking spam, it does nothing to answer the original question (and really should be downvoted as a result).  Postgrey, Spamassassin and RBL's are ways of rejecting spam, rather then replying to it  [ which no doubt you know is a terrible idea ]